# ORA-03146: Invalid buffer length for TTC field

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

when I try to insert record to the table, I get the following error.
I do not have any problems when I perform update and select operations for the same table.

Nhibernate Proviler Insert Command :

```
> INSERT INTO UserOneTimePassword
>            (Id,
>             Password,
>             TryCount,
>             CreatedOn,
>             CreatedBy,
>             ModifiedBy,
>             ModifiedOn,
>             UserId) VALUES     (hibernate_sequence.nextval,
>             '''5618e6e426cffa1136bd078d0c875a81f1e1edd84a74980dfec579007d225424''
> [Type: String (0:0:0)]' /* :p0 */,
>             '0 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]' /* :p1 */,
>             '2017-11-21T09:42:34.0000000 [Type: DateTime (0:0:0)]' /* :p2 */,
>             '0 [Type: Int64 (0:0:0)]' /* :p3 */,
>             'NULL [Type: Int64 (0:0:0)]' /* :p4 */,
>             'NULL [Type: DateTime (0:0:0)]' /* :p5 */,
>             '7 [Type: Int64 (0:0:0)], :nhIdOutParam = NULL [Type: Int64 (0:0:0)]' /* :p6 */) returning Id into :nhIdOutParam
```

***Error :***

---

> > Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> >     ORA-03146: Invalid buffer length for TTC field at
> >     OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32&
> >     cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType
> >     sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException&
> >     exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean
> >     bFirstIterationDone)    at
> >     OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String
> >     commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
> >     commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize,
> >     Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl,
> >     Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
> >     bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException&
> >     exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection,
> >     OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF) 
> >     at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> >     at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
> >     at
> >     NHibernate.Id.Insert.OutputParamReturningDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand
> >     insert, ISessionImplementor session)    at
> >     NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo
> >     insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)

---

---

Comment: English, please.

Comment: I got the same error in the following case: <MY INSERT SQL> + " RETURNING ID INTO :id" where :id was defined as `parameters.Add("id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);`. As seen from the statement, table had a column named ID. I assumed there might be naming conflict of some kind going on. Indeed, renaming the parameter to: `parameters.Add("output_id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);` helped, and following works: <MY INSERT SQL> + "RETURNING ID into :output_id". (parameters is defined as  `new DynamicParameters();`)

Answer (score 0):

- ORA-03146: Invalid buffer length for TTC field
- Cause:  A corrupt Two-Task Common (TTC) packet was received.
- Action:  This is a internal protocol error. **Contact Oracle Support Services.**

[ORA-03146](http://ora.codes/ora-03146/)

Comment: the reference link is dead, please update